Beginner having issues adding metadata to DEseq2 object
I am trying to make a Deseq2 object for analysis but cannot seem to get my metadata df to properly add to the object.
# Simulate reading a gene expression count matrix
spiders_rawcounts <- data.frame(
  gene = paste0("gene", 1:5),  # Example gene names
  rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n2_S1 = rpois(5, 100),
  rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n14_S2 = rpois(5, 150),
  rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n26_S3 = rpois(5, 200),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
rownames(spiders_rawcounts) <- spiders_rawcounts$gene
spiders_rawcounts <- spiders_rawcounts[, -1]

## Meta data 
sample_names <- colnames(spiders_rawcounts)
get_pulse <- function(sample_name) {
  if (grepl("i13", sample_name)) {
    return("yes")
  } else {
    return("no")
  }
}
get_collection_time <- function(sample_name) {
  matches <- regmatches(sample_name, gregexpr("t[0-9]+", sample_name))
  return(as.numeric(sub("t", "", matches[[1]])))
}
# Create the metadata dataframe
spiders_metadata <- data.frame(sample_name = sample_names,collection_times = sapply(sample_names, get_collection_time),
  pulse = sapply(sample_names, get_pulse))
spiders_metadata <- subset(spiders_metadata, select = -sample_name)
spiders_metadata$collection_times <- factor(spiders_metadata$collection_times)
spiders_metadata$pulse <- factor(spiders_metadata$pulse)
## Reordering 
reorder_indices <- match(rownames(spiders_metadata),colnames(spiders_rawcounts))
reordered_spider_rawcounts <- spiders_rawcounts[ , reorder_indices]
## DESeq Object
dds_spiders <-DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = spiders_rawcounts,colData = spiders_metadata,design = ~ collection_times + pulse,)
summary(dds_spiders)

all(colnames(reordered_spider_rawcounts) == rownames(spiders_metadata))

The summary returns DESeqDataSet object of length 184076 with 0 metadata columns and the last line returns TRUE. I have tried troubleshooting and am not sure what to do from here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Response
Alehman responded:
head(spiders_metadata)
                          collection_times pulse
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n2_S1                 3   yes
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n14_S2                3   yes
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n26_S3                3   yes
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n27_S4                3   yes
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n31_S5                3   yes
rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n1_S6                  3    no


Can you just show us what the top few lines of your metadata are?

I don't think there is a problem
> dds_spiders
class: DESeqDataSet 
dim: 5 3 
metadata(1): version
assays(1): counts
rownames(5): gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5
rowData names(0):
colnames(3): rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n2_S1 rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n14_S2 rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n26_S3
colData names(2): collection_times pulse
> colData(dds_spiders)
DataFrame with 3 rows and 2 columns
                          collection_times    pulse
                                  <factor> <factor>
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n2_S1                 3      yes
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n14_S2                3      yes
rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n26_S3                3      yes


yeah, im braindead. Thanks...
